# puppeteer - centos7 - symbol not found

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, centos7, puppeteer

Hi I have a super simple Dockerfile to run puppeteer in Docker:

```
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
  echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
  echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
  apk add --no-cache \
  bash=4.4.19-r1 \
  git=2.20.1-r0 \
  openssh=7.9_p1-r5 \
  chromium@edge \
  nss@edge \
  freetype@edge \
  harfbuzz@edge \
  ttf-freefont@edge \
  sudo=1.8.25_p1-r2

ADD https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.0/dumb-init_1.2.0_amd64 /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install --quiet -g pm2@^3.5.1 && \
    npm install puppeteer@1.19.0 && \
    npm install --quiet

COPY app.js ./app.js

RUN addgroup -S pptruser && adduser -S -g pptruser pptruser \
  && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
  && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
  && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /app

USER pptruser

EXPOSE 1337

CMD [ "pm2-runtime", \
    "start", "app.js", \
    "-i", "max", \
    "--max-memory-restart", "1700M", \
    "--cron", "0 */12 * * *" \
]
```

This was a working solution until now wehn I have run *yum update* on my centos7 host machine. Right after that, the app refuses to work properly generating the following error:

```
Error: LAUNCH_BROWSER
    at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:171:65
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
Error: Failed to launch chrome!
Error relocating /usr/lib/chromium/chrome: _ZNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/chromium/chrome: _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/chromium/chrome: _ZNSt19_Sp_make_shared_tag5_S_eqERKSt9type_info: symbol not found
```

I have failed to find a solution so far to put it back in order :-( Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Seems you're missing some debian dependencies: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently a problem with the recent Chromium version on alpine. See these two issues on github for more information:

- [Issue on the alpine-chrome repository](https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-chrome/issues/39) (opened 3 days ago) with your exact error message
- [Issue on the puppeteer repository](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/4823) (opened 9 Aug)

**Solution**

The solution for now is to downgrade the Chromium version to version 72. Some users also reported that version 73 worked for them. You could also give that a try (`chromium@edge=73.0.3683.103-r0`).

In addition to downgrading Chromium, you also need to downgrade puppeteer to the corresponding version. For Chromium 72 you need to use version `1.11.0`. (more information on [how to detect the Chrome version to use with puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55808398/5627599))

The changed Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
  ...
  chromium@edge=72.0.3626.121-r0 \
...

RUN ...
    npm install puppeteer@1.11.0 && \
```

Comment: It does not appear to be a working solution as downgrading to 72... generates a different puppeteer-related err: Error: Protocol error (Fetch.enable): 'Fetch.enable' wasn't found
    at /app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:183:56
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at CDPSession.send (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:182:12)
    at NetworkManager._updateProtocolRequestInterception (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/NetworkManager.js:145:22)
    at NetworkManager.setRequestInterception (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/NetworkManager.js:134:16)
    at ...

Comment: @DavidZaba Can you try to downgrade puppeteer to version `v1.11.0` (when using chromium 72)? That's the version to be used with that chromium version.

Comment: Using v1.11.0 removes the mentioned error, but the app does not work. I belive it is because the app contains new puppeteer APIs that have been introduced in > 1.11.0 versions. It is a real pitty as we would need to look where to downgrade the app as well. I wish the whole puppeteer thing was more stable. Anyway, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @DavidZaba I added the information to the answer. Sorry, I guess this is the best option until the bugs are fixed.